# Ubuntu 12.04 is stuck in lightdm login (Unity Greeter)

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

The login and Unity Greeter is working. However, if I try to log-in - in a matter of seconds, it would return to the login screen.
This happened when I tried to install a package and I restarted my computer.

I also tried to uninstall, install, re-install, upgrade the lightdm, gdm and gnome.

I installed/reinstalled Ubuntu Desktop/Cinnamon/Gnome3 as well, to try and see if it would work. But it is still the same and I can see the login-lockscreen.

In a matter of seconds, I'll be back to the log-in screen.

Comment: Does opening a guest session work?

Comment: "This happened when I tried to install a package" - What package did you install?

Answer (score 1):

At the login screen, use ctrl-alt-f1 to get to a tty login. Login, then delete ~/.Xauthority . If the X server did not shut down properly during the crash, the orphaned lock file is preventing you from starting X.